# Instant chat app retrieval of chat logs

Tags: mysql, angular, typescript

I'm using Angular 4 Typescript and MySQL to create a chat system. I can post messages to my server.

But, I'm having a hard time of understanding how to retrieve the data. When a user subscribes to the chat channel, I don't want him/her to receive all the chat logs at once. Only the most recent. How would I go about this?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please, visit [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Provide more info on efforts you made and code.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you need the server to talk to the client instead of HTTP polling. HTML5 has server-sent events (SSE) but there's a much better way.

Websockets is the way forward. This way the server can broadcast new chat messages to all clients. npm's socket.io is a great websockets implementation. Moreover, if websockets is not available on the browser (think crappy browsers) it falls back to HTTP polling and failing that it has further fallbacks for really crappy browsers.

Very happily for you, the socket.io hello world app is a chat app. You can see it here and follow the simple tutorial - https://socket.io/get-started/chat/

You can integrate socket.io into Angular very easily. As events are received by the client from the server you can emit these events to an RxJS Subject and anything can subscribe to this subject.

See this Angular info on using RxJS Subjects for inter-component communication - https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service

OK, that's the easy part done. What about getting the messages before the user joined the chat channel. Server side, you should look at message queuing. I'm not greatly experienced here but techs like RabbitMQ are what you need. That should do it but, on the client-side, I would also take a look at RxJS Replay Subjects (a different type of Subject) which can emit events that happened before subscription.

TIP: If you are really going pro you should be using a client-side Angular store such as ngrx. Free tutorials here tend to be rubbish. I would recommend investing in the ngrx tutorial on Udemy. ngrx is what the pro's use.

Comment: Thank you for the help. This is a great start

Comment: Would you say websites like Twitch use ngrx?

Comment: ngrx is all about (1) speed (2) making communication between components a breeze (3) data consistency throughout the site (all components get their data from the same place) - no way to tell if it uses it or not but if its fast and bug free it may well do ;)

Comment: you may ask - why not just get data from backend? coz backend is slow to retrieve data from - 1/2 sec here, 2 secs there - ngrx is an in mem store, instant data access - get the data from the backend, chuck it in the store, BAM - update it as you need to - data access in 0.001 millisecs :) components subscribe to store, get auto notified when store changes data and auto update.